Using external links and scripts in NextJS 14
I am working on a client project using a Rental booking script from PHPJabbers.com. I have already setup the backend and hosted it on http://perranbeachhouse.free.nf/ for now. On their guidance on how to install page and admin panel, it says to copy and paste the three tags below into a WordPress or similar page, and the booking calendar should appear.
<link href="http://perranbeachhouse.free.nf/core/framework/libs/pj/css/pj.bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://perranbeachhouse.free.nf/index.php?controller=pjFront&action=pjActionLoadCss&cid=1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://perranbeachhouse.free.nf/index.php?controller=pjFront&action=pjActionLoad&cid=1&view=3"></script>

The issue I am experiencing is because I am using NextJS 14 with the App Directory and copy and pasting this doesn't appear or show anything at all.
I have tried:

Pasting directly into my NextJS app (component and App.jsx)
Using 'next/head' to put  and  tags into the app
Using React and pasting directly into the index.html

And none of these have worked, I don't understand why it should work in Wordpress but not at all in anything I have tried.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

There is usually a span or div tag to go along with embeds like that, double check the documentation and make sure you aren't missing something.

Also worth reading this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#external-stylesheets you may need to download the css files and references them locally, or find an npm package.

@DevonRay unfortunately not, they just give those three. Here is a https://i.imgur.com/2Eq0JFk.png of the "Install" page on the admin panel.

@DevonRay I have no problem hardcoding the css but the script is where I run into issues, it makes api calls in a large function which I don't really want to edit because it is dynamic down to what the settings on the admin panel are for and then it gives me a cors error in a use effect client file  lol

You should be able to import the script without issue, here are the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script use the next/script component

@DevonRay thank you for all your help, unfortunately the script doesn't seem to work. I've tried this: 'import '../css/bootstrap.css'
import '../css/booking.css'
import Script from 'next/script'
const BookingCalendar = () => {
return 

;
};
export default BookingCalendar;' but the script does not do anything. The CSS does work however with a few tweaks. TIA

Are you seeing any errors in your console?

@DevonRay literally nothing. It's like it's not there at all, but obviously clicking the src link it has a full function.

are you able to share the js file or url?
